# How to restart usb hub with devcon?

Tags: windows, usb, devcon

I have usb hub with 8 devices.

This is the list of my usb devices:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> devcon listclass usb
Listing 16 devices in setup class "USB" (Universal Serial Bus controllers).
USB\VID_045B&PID_0210\6&9217727&0&1                         : Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub
USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&1148BC98&0&0                               : USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A12F&SUBSYS_86941043&REV_31\3&11583659&0&A0: Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB\6&EA5F711&0&2                         : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB\6&EA5F711&0&3                         : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB\6&EA5F711&0&4                         : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_1A40&PID_0101\5&521A615&0&3                         : Generic USB Hub
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB\5&521A615&0&7                         : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB\7&30EB5A49&0&1                        : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB\7&30EB5A49&0&2                        : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB\7&30EB5A49&0&3                        : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB\7&30EB5A49&0&4                        : USB Composite Device
USB\VID_045B&PID_0209\6&EA5F711&0&1                         : Generic USB Hub
USB\VID_045B&PID_0210\5&521A615&0&20                        : Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub
USB\VID_045B&PID_0209\5&521A615&0&4                         : Generic USB Hub
USB\VID_1C4F&PID_0026\6&1412FCC8&0&3                        : USB Composite Device
```

How to reboot root usb hub and each of devices separately?
This is what is have so far:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> devcon restart devcon restart *ROOT_HUB30*
USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&1148BC98&0&0                               : Restart failed
No matching devices found.
```

Also this is the particular 4g modem that i want to reboot

```
USB\VID_12D1&PID_14DB&MI_00\6&FB0441&0&0000
    Name: Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device #32
    Driver is running.
```

but have the same fail result

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in wrong devcon version, I used x86 instead of x64.

Comment: To make that an answer, rather than a comment, show the details: how does the script look now?